# jquery modal dialog doesn't sent multiple data from 2 tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I'm having difficulty with a bootstrap modal lookup (jQuery modal dialog) to retrieve data from 2 tables,

so, I have 2 tables:

```
 first is Student Table
Id      studentCode     studentName

1       S01             Michael Jordan

2       S02             Patric Ewing
```

and the other table:

```
Books

id  studentCode  bookCode  bookName

1    S01         B001      PHP

2    S01         B002      SQL

3    S02         B003       C#

4    S02         B004      Java
```

I have this code that retrieve data using jQuery dialog from the student and books table:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="action" onsubmit="dummy();
            return false">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="varchar">Student Code</label>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentcode" id="studentcode" placeholder="Student Code" readonly />

                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentname" id="studentname" placeholder="Name " readonly />

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">. . .</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<table width="446" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Student Code</th>
    <td><strong>Product Code</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Product Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>QTY</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><label for="studentcode"></label>
      <input type="text" name="student" id="student"></th>
    <td><label for="bookcode"></label>
      <input type="text" name="bookcode" id="bookcode"></td>
    <td><label for="bookname"></label>
      <input type="text" name="bookname" id="bookname"></td>
    <td><label for="qty"></label>
      <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"></td>
  </tr>
</table>


              <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />

        </form>

                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:800px">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>  </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Lookup Student</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table id="lookup" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Student Code</th>
                                    <th>Student Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php

                                $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'obat');
                                $sql = mysqli_query($con,'select * from student p inner join books b on p.studentcode=b.studentcode');
                                while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <tr class="pilih" data="<?php echo $r['studentcode']; ?>", name="<?php echo $r['studentname'] ?>", code="<?php echo $r['bookcode'] ?>", book="<?php echo $r['bookname'] ?>">
                                        <td><?php echo $r['studentcode']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $r['studentname']; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).on('click', '.pilih', function (e) {
                document.getElementById("studentcode").value = $(this).attr('data');
                document.getElementById("studentname").value = $(this).attr('name');
                document.getElementById("student").value = $(this).attr('data');
                document.getElementById("bookcode").value = $(this).attr('code');
                document.getElementById("bookname").value = $(this).attr('book');
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });


            $(function () {
                $("#lookup").dataTable();
            });

        </script>
```

When I click a name, it will send data to the main form. The code successfully sends data to the main form, but for the books table, it only sends 1 line of data

1. How do I retrieve all data from the book table based on student name(code)?
2. I'd like to add a textbox on books table to fill it manually and save it to another table. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I created a test fiddle from your code: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/43fLLc4c/ Can you provide some example data that the PHP would generate? Why is `jquery-ui` tagged?

Comment: Also, based on your tables, when is `p.studentcode=b.studentcode` true?

Comment: I do not see a "books" table. Updated to use jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/43fLLc4c/2/

Comment: thank you for the help, I'm sorry for the unclear question, your jsfiddle @Twisty  is just like what i have in my project, what i want to ask is that michael jordan borrows 2 books, and what I want is when I click on Michael Jordan, the two books that he borrow appear in the table on the main page

Answer (score 0):

Based on your 2 SQL Tables, and the SQL Query:

```
select * from student p inner join books b on p.studentcode=b.studentcode;
```

this will only pull content from `student` table as there are no `b.studentcode` fields that match `p.studentcode` values.

```
B01 != S01
B02 != S02
```

To correct the issue, you will need to ensure that the two columns align in some manner. Either change the value in one or the other so that:

```
B01 == B01
B02 == B02
```

Or:

```
S01 == S01
S02 == S02
```

This will return a record set like:

```
S01  Michael Jordan  B001  PHP
S01  Michael Jordan  B002  SQL
S02  Patric Ewing    B003  C#
S02  Patric Ewing    B004  Java
```

This assumes a few things, like you meant to have "S" represent students, and that `003` was meant to be `B003`. I would also advise a more specific SQL Query:

```
select p.studentCode, p.studentName, b.bookCode, b.bookName from student p inner join books b on p.studentCode=b.studentCode;
```

In your jQuery, I would suggest making use of the `data` attribute versus the ones you've selected to avoid confusion and make for more portable code. For example, look here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/43fLLc4c/3/

**HTML Snippet**

```
<tr class="pilih" data-sc="S01" data-sn="Michael Jordan" data-bc="B001" data-bn="PHP">
  <td>S01</td>
  <td>Michael Jordan</td>
</tr>
<tr class="pilih" data-sc="S01" data-sn="Michael Jordan" data-bc="B002" data-bn="SQL">
  <td>S01</td>
  <td>Michael Jordan</td>
</tr>
<tr class="pilih" data-sc="S02" data-sn="Patric Ewing" data-bc="B003" data-bn="C#">
  <td>S02</td>
  <td>Patric Ewing</td>
</tr>
<tr class="pilih" data-sc="S02" data-sn="Patric Ewing" data-sc="B004" data-bn="Java">
  <td>S02</td>
  <td>Patric Ewing</td>
</tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".pilih").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#studentcode").val($(this).data("sc"));
    $("#studentname").val($(this).data("sn"));
    $("#student").val($(this).data("sn"));
    $("#bookcode").val($(this).data("bc"));
    $("#bookname").val($(this).data("bn"));
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
  });
  $("#lookup").dataTable();
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the effort @Twisty, both of your example on jsfiddle have the same result as mine, all I want is to display the 2 books which Michael Jordan borrow at the same time. So when i click on Michael Jordan's name, the table on the main page retrieve 2 rows of book data.

Comment: Ok. That can be done. There is a way to do this in datatables and via jquery. Can you make an example image of what you would like to see as a result? Also would this detail be coming from php? If not in assuming the user gets all the results at once and you're trying to filter afterward.

Comment: I created it with photoshop, I want to achive something like this  http://i36.photobucket.com/albums/e7/Alraniry/stack_zps5wbbynx8.jpg   I hope you can help me with the code